# Setting custom delegate with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im using the following code to presentViewController where Im setting the delegate.

```
Filters * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FilterMe"];
        vc.filtersDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But im getting the following error,

```
[UINavigationController setFiltersDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1018cf600'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Check what class is "vc". It seems that it is not really Filters.

Comment: Its ofcourse Filters

Comment: The viewcontroller is embedded in NavigationController at storyboard

Comment: you need to set delegate  after viewcontroller present

Comment: can you show ur strotyboard  scene

Comment: The error clearly says that the returned controller is actually UINavigationController.

Comment: @HaraHaraMahadevaki - check once matic answer is correct else change your navigation as `PUSH` or `SHOW`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FilterMe"]` returns an `UINavigationController`.

Check your storyboard but you might need `vc.viewControllers.first` to access your true view controller.

Try:

```
    UINavigationController *navController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FilterMe"];
    Filters *vc = navController.viewControllers.firstObject;
    vc.filtersDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: It says ` 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller `

Comment: @HaraHaraMahadevaki - elsse change `present` to `Show` and try once

Comment: showviewcontroller makes the bottomview (UITabbar) of previous viewcontroller to be visible. Any other alternatives?

Comment: I have set the delegate on completion block and it worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: `UINavigationController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FilterMe"];
        Filters *filters = vc.viewControllers.firstObject;
        
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
            filters.filtersDelegate = self;
        }];`

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard check identifier for your class and also for navigation controller it is embedded in.

Comment: make sure you are instantiating it from correct storyboard.